# GCP Logs Explorer how to search cloud function logs by filter and then get all logs for the matching executionId

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to first search all cloud function logs by a filter, say those that have "memory limit" string in them. For example, here is one log line that is matching:

```
labels: {execution_id: "7384b5uygh7c", instance_id: "00c61b117c482ad198e2bc057ba4bcb50976840ff316c2ac77650b5132428b48e8b4735b4d7c5d2f12aa839d1d8db11e53789613d0a0818bab"}
textPayload: "Memory limit of 256 MiB exceeded with 264 MiB used. Consider increasing the memory limit, see https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/configuring/memory"
```

and then for those that are found - I would like to get the executionId of the matching line and get all log lines from that CF instance run, for example for the **executionId="7384b5uygh7c"**, from the match above - I want to get all available logs that match this executionId:

```
DEBUG 2023-08-06T12:25:09.982670491Z ...[labels.executionId: 7384b5uygh7c] Function execution took 21215 ms, finished with status: 'error'
ERROR 2023-08-06T12:25:06.877980Z ...[labels.executionId: 7384b5uygh7c] Memory limit of 256 MiB exceeded with 264 MiB used. Consider increasing the memory limit, see https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/configuring/memory
INFO 2023-08-06T12:24:49.512769Z ... [labels.executionId: 7384b5uygh7c] header_content_type: text/html
INFO 2023-08-06T12:24:48.961243Z ... [labels.executionId: 7384b5uygh7c] response_code = 200, xxx
INFO 2023-08-06T12:24:48.770980Z ... [labels.executionId: 7384b5uygh7c] Processing input event: {"LOGSTASH_ID": "1t7qidwf3lgwc7", ...}
DEBUG 2023-08-06T12:24:48.767560544Z ... [labels.executionId: 7384b5uygh7c] Function execution started
```

The goal being to get LOGSTASH_IDs of all logs that failed to process due to this error, for further troubleshooting ... and LOGSTASH_IDs are written in separate log lines from the memory errors - unfortunately, the memory error is not coming from CF, I can't catch it there and log with the ID of interest - this error is thrown by CF runtime in GCP :(

I can manually copy the executionId and do a separate search by it - but having hundreds and thousands of logs like this to investigate - manual approach is just not feasible ...

Any idea how I could do this using GCP Logs query language - or any other practical way?

Thank you!
Marina

Answer (score 0):

Just as I typed the question - I started searching Goggle docs again - and found info on "log correlation": https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/correlate-logs
which turned out to be exactly what I needed!

So to do what I described in the original question - you have to first search logs by your filter value (like "memory limit") in my case, and then when the results are displayed, go to "Correlate by" and pick "Cloud function" as the option - it will show all log lines from each cloud function execution where there is a String like "memory limit" in any of that run's log lines!

Perfect :)